# nginx & php5-fpm respond extremely slow with Laravel application

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, nginx

I am running a PHP application (Laravel and MySQL) on a Ubuntu VPS with nginx and php5-fpm installed (both with default settings). I soon experienced some totally random 502 errors, apparently due to php5-fpm which timed out and lost connection to nginx every now and then.

I was desperately looking for a solution on SO and any other resource I could find, but the error persisted: The webserver didn't respond about 40 times over 2 days, with a "downtime" of about 2 mins each. I changed the workers in php5-fpm, the maximum execution time... nothing. The server only showed very low CPU and RAM usage.

I eventually killed the VPS and set up a new one from scratch - with the same result. But instead of showing 502 errors, the request simply takes about 40 secs of constant loading without any content or error displayed. And about 2 mins later, once I hit reload the page loads instantly.

The only thing left I could think of was changing php5-fpm. What I did. I tried using hhvm. But again the same result of constant loading.

I seriously don't know what to do anymore... did anyone of you run into the same problem before?

Cheers

Comment: Maybe it's something in your application if a fresh vm is encountering the same issue?

Comment: Trying installing the laravel debugbar, could give you some in-site as to what is slowing your requests. I suspect its possibly your queries or something in your code slowing things if it occurs on a new environment.  https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

Comment: I though of that too, but how can I test if there is something wrong with the application? I just discovered **slow logs** in php5-fpm and will give them a try

Comment: Have you tried a fresh laravel install?

Comment: Oh my god I think I found the error with **slow logs**: I'm using a Geojson request to an external service to find out if I should either display EUR or USD on the pricing page. And I think this delayed it and caused the random errors! I will investigate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of **slow logs** I found the issue, it was an external service (GeoJSON request) that randomly slowed down the page and therefore caused the error.